# How to check if image was submitted with other form data

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have an user registration form and uploading image with other form elements is optional there. So sometimes users may not upload image along with other data.

Now the problem is even though the user has not uploaded image, the following code always echos that the file was uploaded

Could you please kindly tell me how  to check if the image was submitted by the user and make it echo/display "not uploaded" if not uploaded ?

Thanks in Advance :)

In my Controller File

```
extract($_POST); // <<This is to retrieve all form data at once

if(isset($_FILES['userfile'])){
    echo"file uploaded";
} else{
    echo "Not Uploaded";
}
```

This is in my View File

```
<input type="file" class="" name="userfile" size="20" />
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Per PHP documentation:

If no file is selected for upload in your form, PHP will return $_FILES['userfile']['size'] as 0, and $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] as none.

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

So your conditional can change to:

```
if(isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0){
     echo"file uploaded";
} else echo "Not Uploaded" ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine both checks:

```
 if (count($_POST) and !empty($_FILES['userfile'])) {

       // uploaded

 }
 else {

       // either is missing

 }
```

Note that you should **not** use `extract($_POST);`. You can't control which local variables get overwritten from the outside with that. (If nothing else investigate `EXTR_PREFIX`.)